# Date Time formatting with milliseconds

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

How can I format the Date and Time format to present 'YYYY-MM-DD-HHmmSSSSS'. 
Example 2014-02-05-091122589

Answer (score 1):

Use `fff` with `DateTime.ParseExact`:

```
DateTime dtWithMillis = DateTime.ParseExact("2014-02-05-091122589", "yyyy-MM-dd-HHmmssfff", null);
```

[The "fff" Custom Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#fffSpecifier)